# python, kivymd, builder, loadfile

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a seemingly pretty easy question. I am making a app with kivymd and the first .kv file is sort of long. I have three .kv files that I would like to navigate in between. Currently i'm wondering how to use Builder.load_file, or something else to read from window to window, thanks for your help.

Comment: To load a file in `kvlang` you can use [directive](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#include-file) syntax or in `python` use [`Builder.load_file`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#kivy.lang.BuilderBase.load_file).

Comment: But take care to avoid loading the same `kv` file multiple times. That can lead to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way to do this or not. I myself couldn't find anything but ended up doing the following.

1. Create your main .kv file that is a screen manager. Make sure you include your other .kv files with '#:include 'filename.kv'

   ```
   #:include screen1.kv
   #:include screen2.kv


   ScreenManager:
       Screen1:
       Screen2:
   ```
2. Format your other .kv files however you'd like. Just make sure to include a name for referencing in your screen manager. You must also name the screens the same as you did in your main.kv file.

   ```
    <Screen1>
        name: 'screen1'
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Screen1'
            halign: 'center'

        MDFlatButton:
            text: 'Go to screen 2'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen2'
   ```

This is .kv file #2

```
    <Screen2>
        name: 'screen2'
         orientation: 'vertical'

        MDLabel:
            text: 'Screen2'
            halign: 'center'

        MDFlatButton:
            text: 'Go to screen 1'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'screen1'
```

Your main.py file will have to include the libraries, define the classes, add the screens to your screen manager, and then you can build your main.kv file in your MDApp.

```
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
    from kivy.lang import Builder

    class Screen1(Screen):
        pass

    class Screen2(Screen):
        pass

    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(Screen1(name= 'screen1'))
    sm.add_widget(Screen2(name= 'screen2'))

    class MainApp(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            sm = Builder.load_file("Main.kv")
            return sm

    MainApp().run()
```